# Why do I get a "! Missing \right. inserted." message?

Tags: equations, amsmath

What's wrong with this?

Error message: "! Missing \right. inserted." (But I don't see it. Everythink works!)

```
\begin{multline}
U=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\left[(a_{nk}\cos n\varphi + b_{nk}\sin n\varphi)\cos\frac{a\mu_{nk}t}{R} \\
+(c_{nk}\cos n\varphi + d_{nk}\sin n\varphi)\sin\frac{a\mu_{nk}t}{R}\right] J_n\left(\mu_{nk}\frac{\varrho}{R}\right)
\end{multline}
```

Comment: You have to close the `\left[` with `\right.` before the line break and open with `\left.` on the next line.

Comment: Using `\left` and `\right` in different lines might result in mismatching sizes. It is better to size the brackets with `\big` or similar.

Comment: @Hello I see a parade of questions coming from you over the last few hours. Before asking a new question, if u find the answer of your previous question satisfactory, please consider accepting it :)

Comment: Since the `multline` material is automatically in display-style math mode, the `\limits` qualifiers are redundant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't overuse `\left` and `\right` to auto-size large parentheses. Not only will this get you into trouble if these directives span a line break -- as is the case in your example code -- it will quite often also fail to generate the typographically appropriate sizes for the parentheses. For the case at hand, I believe `\Bigl(` and `\Bigr)` is far more appropriate.

I would also like to suggest to you that you use a `split` environment instead of a `multline` environment, as there's a fairly natural way to align the two rows to make their common structures more readily apparent. Finally, consider using inline-fraction notation for the three expressions that contain `R` in the denominator. Oh, and do get rid of the two `\limits` directives: they do nothing here except add code clutter.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'split' env.
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
U=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}
\Bigl[&(a^{}_{nk}\cos n\varphi + b^{}_{nk}\sin n\varphi)
\cos(a\mu^{}_{nk}t/R) \\
{}+{}&(c^{}_{nk}\cos n\varphi + d^{}_{nk}\sin n\varphi)
\sin(a\mu^{}_{nk}t/R)\Bigr] 
J_n(\mu^{}_{nk}\varrho/R)
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\big` size is more than sufficient.

Comment: @egreg - I agree that `\big` suffices in a way, especially if one goes with a `multline` environment. If one employs a `split` environment, though, using `\Big` helps to reveal, aesthetically speaking, the overall structure of the equation. In my opinion, the equation shows above looks a bit weak if one uses `\big` instead of `\Big`. Of course, as the ancient Romans were amply aware, *de gustibus non est disputandum*...

Answer (score 3):

Just for fun:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\bracketed}[1]{\left[\vphantom{\let\\=\relax #1}\right. #1 \left.\vphantom{\let\\=\relax #1}\right]}

\begin{document}
\begin{multline}
U=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\bracketed{(a_{nk}\cos n\varphi + b_{nk}\sin n\varphi)\cos\frac{a\mu_{nk}t}{R} \\
+(c_{nk}\cos n\varphi + d_{nk}\sin n\varphi)\sin\frac{a\mu_{nk}t}{R}} J_n\left(\mu_{nk}\frac{\varrho}{R}\right)
\end{multline}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Might be for fun, but works.