# How to maintain large brackets in a split environment?

Tags: math-mode, align, brackets, split

For example, I want to write

```
\begin{equation}
 \begin{split}
    \left\{ &ax + b =\\
            & cx + d \right\}
  \end{split}
\end{equation}
```

Latex tells me I annot split the brackets like this, for there is a \left without a \right, and vice versa.

How to treat this issue?

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/460793/why-do-i-get-a-missing-right-inserted-message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `\left\{` you should use `\bigl\{` (or `\Bigl\{`, `\biggl\{` ...) and `\bigl\{` (or `\Bigr\{`, `\biggr\{` ...) instead of `\right\}` :

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
 \begin{split}
    \bigl\{ &ax + b =\\
            & cx + d \bigr\}
  \end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]